# readfile() sometimes stops before end of file

Tags: php, filesize, readfile

I have a script which sends a ZIP file. It's a 12MB large file but sometimes, in rare cases, download stops at 4MB, 5MB, 6.5MB (never the same)...

```
<?php

$fullpath = 'foobar.zip';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fullpath);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($fullpath));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fullpath);
exit();

?>
```

In what conditions readfile() can stops before having read all the file? Is there anything else wrong?

Comment: must be a server lag or some bandwidth problem

Comment: Yes, also thought about the time limit. Whats the value of that (do a php_info())?

Comment: It is set to 120 second. I did `set_time_limit(0)` as @RezaSh suggested and will wait for any further failures.

Comment: It seems to be an hoster-related transient problem.